# jQuery .dialog inside .each loop - new dialog content divs are written on each iteration - how can I destroy the old divs on each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a webpage that is using ajax GET to download an xml file, then a function (xmlParser) parses the xml file in an .each loop. Inside the same .each loop, I am creating jQuery dialog boxes.

The ajax GET mentioned above re-runs every 1 second because the xml file it is getting is dynamic. Everything on the page works correctly (i.e. all content displays and functions properly), but when I look at the page Elements in Chrome's developer console, I noticed that the divs for the dialog content are being recreated everytime the ajax function loops, which eventually causes the page to crash.

How can I prevent this? I can't seem to figure out a way to properly overwrite these divs to stop new ones from being created each time.

I would really appreciate someone's help.

The full code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8">
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 9]>
  <html class="ie ie9">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]>
    <!-->
    <html>
      <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-ui-theme-css'  href='css1.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='googlefonts-css'  href='css2.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='css3.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='css4.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='main-css'  href='css5.css' media='all' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='red-css'  href='css6.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' id='responsive-css'  href='css7.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval("ajaxd()", 1000);
});
function ajaxd() {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "output.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: xmlParser
    });
};
function xmlParser(xml) {
    "use strict";
    $(".main2").empty();
    //$(".main").html(''); //blank out appended info on each load

    $('#load').hide();
    var count = 1;
    $(xml).find("proc").each(function () {
        var ip = $(this).find("ip").text();
        var hdBlackGain = $(this).find("hdBlackGain").text();
        var hdLumaGain = $(this).find("hdLumaGain").text();
        var hdChromaGain = $(this).find("hdChromaGain").text();
        var hdHue = $(this).find("hdHue").text();
        var machineName = $(this).find("machineName").text();

        if (hdBlackGain === '0' && hdLumaGain === '0' && hdChromaGain === '0' && hdHue === '0') {
        } else {
            $(".main2").append('<div class="proc"><div class="title"><div class="dialog_but">' + machineName + '</div><div class="dialog_content"><ul><li>Black Gain: ' + hdBlackGain + '</li><li>Luma Gain: ' + hdLumaGain + '</li><li>Chroma Gain: ' + hdChromaGain + '</li><li>Hue: ' + hdHue + '</li><li>IP Address: ' + ip + '</li></ul></div></div></div>');
            $(".proc").show();

        //loop through every button anchor element
        $('.dialog_but').each(function() {

            //create a local scope of a dialog variable to attach
            var $dialog;

            //create the dialog for the div.dialog_content standing next to the anchor element
            //we make the autoOpen false so that it can be reusable
            //also we set the modal = true to appear the dialog as a modal prompt
            $dialog = $(this).next('div.dialog_content').dialog({
              modal: true,
              autoOpen: false,
              width: 600,
              title: 'Current Proc Status: ' + machineName,
              buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  ]
            });

            //now attach the open even of the dialog to the anchor element
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                //prevent the anchor element to go to the hyperlinked page
                e.preventDefault();

                //open the dialog
                $dialog.dialog('open');
            });
        });
            count = count + 1;
        }
    });
};
</script>
<style> 
.main2{
width:1150px;
margin:0 auto;
height:130px;
}

.proc{
width:208px;
float:left;
margin:10px;
border:1px #dedede solid;
padding:5px;
display:none;
background-color:#A0492E;
}

.title{
text-align:center;
color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="boxed home-3">
      <div class="wrap">
        <!-- Header Start -->
        <header id="header">
          <!-- Main Header Start -->
          <div class="main-header">
            <div class="container">
              <!-- TopNav Start -->
              <div class="topnav navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-toggle down-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".slidedown"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down icon-current"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <!-- TopNav End -->
              <!-- Logo Start -->
              <div class="logo pull-left">
                <h1>
                  <a href="http://bcceng">
                    <img src="http://bcceng/wp-content/themes/opseng/img/logo.png" alt="Text goes here" width="222" height="32" style="vertical-align: baseline !important;"></a>
                </h1>
              </div>
              <!-- Logo End --> </div>
          </div></header>
          <!-- Main Header End -->
          <!-- Content Start -->
          <div id="main">
            <!-- Slogan Start-->
            <div class="slogan bottom-pad-small">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="slogan-content">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                      <h2 class="slogan-title">Text goes here</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slogan End-->
            <!-- Main Content start-->
            <div class="main-content">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div align="center">Text goes here</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="main2">
                  <div align="center" class="loader">
                    <img src="loader.gif" id="load" alt="Please wait..." width="16" height="11" align="absmiddle"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <p>
                  <br>
                  <br></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <ul>
                <li>
                  <p>Last updated: 3/4/15 11:34pm</p>
                </li>            
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Main Content end--> </div>
        <!-- Content End -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <footer id="footer"></footer>
      <!-- Wrap End -->
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use one dialog and set it's content and title based on events. Running your code every second seems pretty aggressive

Comment: @charlietfl This is what I am now doing Arun's suggestion below. He detailed it out for me a little bit more. The 1 second refresh interval is necessary because this is super-time sensitive information.

Comment: Detail level is the same, just slightly different approach. My version you just leave the html the same with exception of what's noted in my answer, whereas the other version is updating individual elements within the dialog - mine grabs what you are already generating as one block.

Comment: @charlietfl I certainly appreciate your response. Added an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create dialog objects, there are elements which are added to the body which are not under the container `main2`, so calling `$(".main2").empty()` will not remove them.

In your case since the dialogs are created for elements `dialog_content` you can call the [destroy method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) of [dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) to remove them

```
$('.dialog_content').dialog('destroy');
$(".main2").empty();
```

---

Another option is to use a single dialog like

Add below html to your body

```
<div class="dialog_content">
    <ul>
        <li>Black Gain: <span class="hd-black-gain"></span></li>
        <li>Luma Gain: <span class="hd-luma-gain"></span></li>
        <li>Chroma Gain: <span class="hd-chroma-gain"></span></li>
        <li>Hue: <span class="hd-hue"></span></li>
        <li>IP Address: <span class="ip"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("ajaxd()", 1000);

    var $dialog = $('.dialog_content').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Current Proc Status: ',
        buttons: [{
            text: "OK",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });

    $('.main2').on('click', '.dialog_but', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data();
        e.preventDefault();

        $dialog.dialog('option', 'title', 'Current Proc Status: ' + data.machineName);
        $dialog.find('.hd-black-gain').text(data.hdBlackGain);
        $dialog.find('.hd-luma-gain').text(data.hdLumaGain);
        $dialog.find('.hd-chroma-gain').text(data.hdChromaGain);
        $dialog.find('.hd-hue').text(data.hdHue);
        $dialog.find('.ip').text(data.ip);

        //open the dialog
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    })
});

function ajaxd() {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "output.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: xmlParser
    });
};

function xmlParser(xml) {
    "use strict";
    $(".main2").empty();
    //$(".main").html(''); //blank out appended info on each load

    $('#load').hide();
    var count = 1;
    $(xml).find("proc").each(function () {
        var ip = $(this).find("ip").text();
        var hdBlackGain = $(this).find("hdBlackGain").text();
        var hdLumaGain = $(this).find("hdLumaGain").text();
        var hdChromaGain = $(this).find("hdChromaGain").text();
        var hdHue = $(this).find("hdHue").text();
        var machineName = $(this).find("machineName").text();

        if (hdBlackGain === '0' && hdLumaGain === '0' && hdChromaGain === '0' && hdHue === '0') {} else {
            var $proc = $('<div class="proc"><div class="title"><div class="dialog_but">' + machineName + '</div></div></div>').appendTo(".main2");
            $proc.find('.dialog_but').data({
                machineName: machineName,
                hdBlackGain: hdBlackGain,
                hdLumaGain: hdLumaGain,
                hdChromaGain: hdChromaGain,
                hdHue: hdHue,
                ip: ip
            })

            count = count + 1;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your first suggestion of calling the destroy method of dialog, and that did prevent so many divs from being created outside the main2 container, but it also caused any open dialogs to be closed when the ajaxd function hit its refresh interval.

So, I went with your second suggestion. It is working, but I did run into one issue (see comment below).

Comment: The "buttons" were not being displayed on the page after load. I did a comparison between the last version of my code and this one, and I found that each "proc" div on the old code was having "style="display: block;" somehow added into the div container. I cannot figure out what was adding this to the container.
In the internal CSS in my code above, you will see "display:none;" is defined under the .proc class. After updating my code to reflect the changes you proposed above, then changing "display:none;" to "display:block;" everything is now working (i.e. the buttons are visible on the page).

Comment: I just cannot figure out why this is happening the way it is. Why did I not have to change this to "display:block;" in the internal CSS in my old code?

Thank you so much for your suggestion above. My code is now working properly. My curiosity just has the best of me for what I explained above. Any thoughts you may have would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since your html has such a short life span to me it makes sense not to add the extra overhead of creating a bunch of dialogs and event handlers that individually have a very low likelihood of being used.

Recycling one dialog is very easy

You could put a title attribute on the element that is being clicked, and extract the html on demand.

---

Add a permanent dialog to the page:

```
<div id="dialog">

$('#dialog').dialog({ /* your options*/});
```

Modify your html strings in the xml parsing code:

```
<div class="dialog_but" title="Current Proc Status: ' + machineName+'">
```

Then for your click handler you can put this in your page load code and remove it from the xml parser

```
$(document).on('click','.dialog_but',function(){
     var title = this.title,
         content = $(this).next('div.dialog_content').html();
     $('#dialog').html(content).dialog('option','title', title).dialog('open');
});
```

One added step would be to add a css rule to hide `.proc .dialog_content`

CSS

```
.proc .dialog_content{display:none}
```